# Trouble extracting values from JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json

Okay, I'm struggling here. I am getting the following JSON formated string from my php server (called "result") (edited! I was missing a curly brace at the end):

> {"L1":[{"UserName":"User1","Avatar":"1"},{"UserName":"User2","Avatar":"2"},{"UserName":"User3","Avatar":"3"}],"L2":[{"UserName":"User4","Avatar":"4"},{"UserName":"User5","Avatar":"5"}]}

I'm trying to extract an ArrayList with the Avatar numbers from the L1 object(?). But I get an error

> org.json.JSONException: Value
>   [{"UserName":"User1","Avatar":"1"},{"UserName":"User2","Avatar":"2"},{"UserName":"User3","Avatar":"3"}]
>   at L1 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Here's my code:

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONObject("L1"));
                ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        arrList.add(json.getInt("Avatar"));
                        AvatarList = arrList;
                    }
                }
                String query_result = "SUCCESS";
                if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {

                } else {
                    setAvatars(AvatarList);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
```

If I use

```
jsonObject.getJSONArray("L1")
```

I get the same error.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

(edit: I made a mistake in the original post. There was a missing curly brace in the JSON string. Thanks to those who caught that)

Comment: If you view this json in jsonlint.com you will see that it is not properly formatted

Comment: Also play around with http://jsonpath.com/

Comment: your json is invalid. Format it properly at backend.. Paste json `jsoneditoronline.org` to verify errors.

Comment: Two things. First, I had a missing "}" at the end of the JSON string in my post, so fixed that, but it doesn't fix the issue. Second, @atulquest93, thanks for that link that will be super helpful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one.Its working fine. I'm using json-simple-1.1.1 jar

```
         String r="{\"L1\":[{\"UserName\":\"User1\",\"Avatar\":\"1\"},{\"UserName\":\"User2\",\"Avatar\":\"2\"},{\"UserName\":\"User3\",\"Avatar\":\"3\"}],\"L2\":[{\"UserName\":\"User4\",\"Avatar\":\"4\"},{\"UserName\":\"User5\",\"Avatar\":\"5\"}]}";

         Object obj=JSONValue.parse(r);  
         JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;  

        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("L1");

        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (jsonArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                arrList.add((Integer.parseInt((String) json.get("Avatar"))));
                AvatarList = arrList;
            }
        }
        String query_result = "SUCCESS";
        if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {

        } else {
            setAvatars(AvatarList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me if anyone stumbles upon this. I don't really understand why this worked and my original method didn't... something to do with JSONObjects vs JSONArrays vs Strings and things like [, {, }, and ] probably.

```
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("L1"));
                ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        arrList.add(json.getInt("Avatar"));
                        AvatarList = arrList;
                    }
                }
```